# Unable to use INSERT within CTE

Tags: postgresql, cte

I am trying to use a CTE to insert some random data into a table -

```
create table foo (id integer)

with x as (select random())
  insert into foo (id)
  select x from x
```

This gives an error:
`ERROR:  column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type record`

Just the CTE with `select` works:

```
with x as (select random())
--   insert into foo (id)
  select x from x
```

I am also unable to typecast:

```
with x as (select random())
  insert into foo (id)
  select x::integer from x
```

This gives an error: `ERROR:  cannot cast type record to integer`.

What's going wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select x from x
```

means select entire row as column (note the parentheses in output, not pure number). Like value of composite type.

For example,

```
melkij=> select pg_am.* from pg_am limit 1;
 oid | amname |      amhandler       | amtype 
-----+--------+----------------------+--------
   2 | heap   | heap_tableam_handler | t

melkij=> select pg_am from pg_am limit 1;
              pg_am              
---------------------------------
 (2,heap,heap_tableam_handler,t)
```

To get the value of a function, you need to access a specific column, not the entire row.

```
with x as (select random()) select x.random from x;
-- or
with x as (select random() as r) select r from x;
-- or
with x(r) as (select random()) select r from x;
```

you can use the value in insert

```
with x as (select random() as r)
  insert into foo (id)
  select r from x;
```